# Swap Function is not swapping elements of 2D array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, transpose

So this transpose function is supposed to swap elements of 2d array but it is not swapping it.

Output of program is same as its input.

```
input:
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
output:
      123456789
```

I even tried replacing swap function with my swapping code in which you use temp variable to swap two elements which is also not working, so i have no idea what is going on.

```
void transpose(int input_arr[][3], int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                swap(input_arr[i][j], input_arr[j][i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cout << input_arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        const int n = 3;
        int row = 3;
        int col = 3;
        int input_arr[n][n];

        arr(input_arr, n);
        transpose(input_arr, n);
    }
```

Comment: This is where some debugging would have given you an idea what was wrong. If you don't have a good debugger like the one in Visual Studio (that can step through the code 1 line at a time, an alternate method would be to print the output before and after each swap

Comment: What is your expected ouput ?

Comment: Try with a 2x2 array and walk through the code.

Comment: @SidS my expected output is 147258369 also i figured out why my code wasn't working and also now i know how to correctly do it, but since i am new here i don't know if i should delete my question or should i answer it myself but then again answering it myself looks just weird

Comment: Answering yourself is acceptable, although you should check if you are duplicating the work of the other answer(s) before you attempt to post an answer. Remember the main goal of a StackOverflow question is not to help the person asking the question but actually to help readers in the future with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making too many swaps.:)

For example when `i` is equal to `0` and `j` is equal to `1` you are swapping

```
input_arr[0][1] and input_arr[1][0]
```

When `i` is equal to `1` and `j` is equal to `0` you are again swapping

```
input_arr[1][0] and input_arr[0][1]
```

only in the reverse order.

I can suggest the following solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, size_t N>
void transpose( T ( &a )[N][N] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < N; j++ ) 
        {
            std::swap( a[i][j], a[j][i] );
        }           
    }
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
std::ostream & display( const T ( &a )[N][N],std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            os << a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        os << '\n';
    }

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N1 = 3;
    int a1[N1][N1] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    display( a1 ) << '\n';

    transpose( a1 );

    display( a1 ) << '\n';

    const size_t N2 = 4;
    char a2[N2][N2] =
    {
        { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }, 
        { 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' },
        { 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L' },
        { 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P' }
    };

    display( a2 ) << '\n';

    transpose( a2 );

    display( a2 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

1 4 7 
2 5 8 
3 6 9 

A B C D 
E F G H 
I J K L 
M N O P 

A E I M 
B F J N 
C G K O 
D H L P
```

Comment: @SidS It works for any square matrix with elements of ant swappable type because there is used a template function.